# Use the WHERE method to replace all numbers in a Numpy array with a - 1

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to use the where method to replace all odd numbers from the below array with a -1

`np.array([0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9])`

I've tried using the below, but it's not working.

`np.where(Q9 % 2 == 1) = - 1`

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where` method only returns indices

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9])
arr[np.where(arr%2!=0)] = -1
print(arr)
```

output:

```
[ 0 -1  0 -1  0 -1  0 -1  0 -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace in the original array, `where` is not needed, use simple indexing:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9])

a[a%2==1] = -1

a
```

For a new array:

```
b = np.where(a%2==1, -1, a)
```

output: `array([ 0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1])`